# Passport JWT Strategy extracting options

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js, passport-local

**Using Passport JWT Strategy**, I'm passing the token down via `params`, and extracting the token like this `ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter('secret_token')`.

But sometimes I'm passing the token down via `header`, I would like to extract it like this `ExtractJWT.fromHeader('secret_token')`.

How can I check how its being passed down and use the correct *extracting method dynamically*.

This is my code:

```
passport.use(new JWTstrategy({
  secretOrKey: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter('secret_token')

}, async (token, done) => {
  try {
    //Pass the user details to the next middleware
    return done(null, token.user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
}));
```

Thank you! Im on this for a long time....

Answer (score 4):

Use *ExtractJwt.fromExtractors()* method

```
var jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy({
// this will try to extract from Query parm, header and Authheader
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter("secret_token"), ExtractJwt.fromHeader("secret_token"), ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()]),
//here we have defined all possible extractors in an array
  secretOrKey: process.env.AUTH_SECRET
}, async (payload, done) => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The method has been added to extract token from header. Pass it as:

- `Authorization: Bearer {token}`
- `Content-Type : application/json`

```
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this way :

```
const options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter('secret_token')!=undefined?ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter('secret_token'):ExtractJWT.fromHeader('secret_token');
options.secretOrKey = process.env.AUTH_SECRET;

passport.use(new JWTstrategy(options, async (token, done) => {
  try {
    //Pass the user details to the next middleware
    return done(null, token.user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
}));
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, it will only evaluate the first parameter.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:**

Here is a workaround...

It looks for `query params` or `headers` with the name `secret_token` .

```
var url = require('url');

const options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = (request) => {
  var token = null;
  var param_name = 'secret_token' //parameter name 
  var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url, true);

  if (request.headers[param_name]) {
    token = request.headers[param_name];
  }
  else if (parsed_url.query && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsed_url.query, param_name)) {
    token = parsed_url.query[param_name];
  }
  return token;
}
options.secretOrKey = process.env.AUTH_SECRET;

passport.use(new JWTstrategy(options, async (token, done) => {
  try {
    //Pass the user details to the next middleware
    return done(null, token.user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
}));
```